# Reading Data From $_POST[] in PHP

Tags: php, http, post

I'm trying to read POST data in a PHP script.

My first instincts led me to the `$_POST[]` array, but for whatever reason, it's never populated.

I'm using HTTP Client for OS X, http://ditchnet.org/httpclient/ to send POST requests.
I enter the URL of the script, set the method to POST, set the content-type header to text/plain and then enter `myVar=foobar` as the body of the request.

I hit send, and there's nothing in the `$_POST[]` array.

I tried another route after reading some questions here on StackOverflow, and tried reading from the `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`, but no dice there either.
I also tried reading from the `php://input` stream, and nothing.

As a heads up, I'm able to read from the `$_GET[]` array if I add some parameters to the URL, but I don't want to do that.

I also need to post the data from a different application, so I can't use the HTML post forms...

Any help would be awesome, thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the Content-Type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. text/plain is [not](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) a valid content type for post data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the raw request-body, you can use:

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: I really like that method, even though it's almost never actually required.

Answer (score -1):

Check to see if post works from a browser... I would suspect the HTTP client you're using is not sending the request properly.

The GET request is considerably simpler than a multipart POST request.